# condition check for null field on radio button selection

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

[image]I have a sign up page where i have **two radio buttons** I am **a company** or I am **an individual.** If i selects a company then two fields will appear on the screen company name & registration number and if i select **an individual** then three fields will appear on the screen **Identification document**, **Identification number** and annual income

I am facing a validation issue as after selecting **an individual** if i left identification field blank it doesn't give me proper error.

> Below is my code

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

            var maxDate = new Date().getDate() - 6570;
            $('#dob').datepicker({autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true,format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',endDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(maxDate))});
            $('#dob1').datepicker({autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true,format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',endDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(maxDate))});

            $('#industry').select2();
            $('#industry1').select2();
            $('#country').select2();
            $('#annual_income').select2();
            $('#identification_document').select2();
            $('#designation1').select2();
            $('#practices').select2();
            $('#countryCode').select2();
            $('#counCode').select2();
            $('#sign_up').click(function () {
                fname = $("#fname").val();
                lname = $("#lname").val();
                if($('#country').select2('data') != null){
                    country = $('#country').select2('data').text;
                }else {
                    country = "";
                }

                if($('#countryCode').select2('data') != null){
                    code1 = $('#countryCode').select2('data').text;
                }else {
                    code1 = "";
                }
                contact1 = $('#contactNo1').val();
                email = $("#email").val();
                client_iam = $('input[name=inlineRadioOptions]:checked').val();
                company = $('#client_company').val();
                companyreg = $('#client_company_reg').val();
                identification_number = $('#identification_num').val();
                if($('#identific ation_document').select2('data') != null){
                    identification_document = $('#identification_document').select2('data').text;
                }else {
                    identification_document = "";
                }
                if($('#annual_income').select2('data') != null){
                    annual_income = $('#annual_income').select2('data').text;
                }else {
                    annual_income = "";
                }
                password = $("#password").val();
                cnf_password = $("#cnf_password").val();
                role = "client";
                var email_Format = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
                if(!(email_Format).test(email)){
                    show_notification('error', 'Please enter email in abc@xyz.com format only!');
                    return false;
                }
                if (fname == "" || lname == "" || country == "" || code1 == "" || contact1 =="" || email == "" || password == "") {
                    show_notification("error", "Please enter all required fields");
                }else if(($('input[name="inlineRadioOptions"]:checked').length == 0)) {
                        show_notification('error', 'Please select as you want to signup as a company or an individual.');
                }else if(company == "" || companyreg == ""){
                    show_notification('error', "please enter company and registration number!!!"); //here is issue i am facing when i left identification_number blank it gives me company field error.
                }else if(identification_number == ''){
                    show_notification('error', "enter identification number");
                }else{
                    if (password != cnf_password) {
                        show_notification("error", "Password and confirm password doesn't match");
                    } else {
                        if(!$('#client_terms_checkbox').is(':checked')){
                            show_notification("error","Please accept terms & conditions");
                        }else {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "reg",
                                type: "POST",
                                headers: {
                                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                },
                                data: {
                                    fname: fname,
                                    lname: lname,
                                    country: country,
                                    role: role,
                                    company : company,
                                    code: code1,
                                    contact: contact1,
                                    client_iam: client_iam,
                                    companyreg:companyreg,
                                    identification_document: identification_document,
                                    identification_number: identification_number,
                                    annual_income: annual_income,
                                    email: email,
                                    password: password,
                                    postlogin: localStorage.postlogin
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    localStorage.removeItem("postlogin");
                                    show_notification("success", "Registered Successfully");
                                    setTimeout(function (result) {
                                        window.location.href = data;
                                    }, 1000);
                                },
                                error: function (data) {
                                    show_notification("error", data.responseJSON.message);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated...

> HTML code:

```
 <div class="card-body tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="first1">
                            <div class="form">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px;width: 100%;margin-top: 10px;" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="fname" >
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" >First Name*</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px; width: 100%;   margin-top: 10px;" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname">
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" >Last Name*</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group"  style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                            <select style="margin-top: 25px;" id="country" class="form-control " name="country">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value=""> Brunei</option>
                                                <option value=""> Cambodia</option>
                                                <option value=""> Indonesia</option>
                                                <option value=""> Laos</option>
                                                <option value=""> Malaysia</option>
                                                <option value=""> Myanmar</option>
                                                <option value=""> Philippines</option>
                                                <option value=""> Singapore</option>
                                                <option value=""> Thailand</option>
                                                <option value=""> Vietnam</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" for="">Select Country*</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                            <select style="margin-top: 25px;" id="countryCode" class="form-control select2-list" name="phone">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value=""> +673</option>
                                                <option value=""> +855</option>
                                                <option value=""> +62</option>
                                                <option value=""> +856</option>
                                                <option value=""> +60</option>
                                                <option value=""> +95</option>
                                                <option value=""> +63</option>
                                                <option value=""> +65</option>
                                                <option value=""> +66</option>
                                                <option value=""> +84</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" for="">Country code</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" for="">Contact Number*</label>
                                            <input type="number" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px;width: 100%;margin-top: 13px;" class="form-control" name="phone1" id="contactNo1" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0;">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-1" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0;text-align: center;"> I am</div>
                                            <div class="col-md-11" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                                                <label class="radio-inline radio-styled" style="margin-right: 20px;" >
                                                    <input style="" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="company_redio" value="company"><label for="">a company</label>
                                                </label>
                                                <label class="radio-inline radio-styled">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="individual_redio" value="an individual"><label for="">an individual</label>
                                                </label>
                                            </div><!--end .col -->
                                        </div><!--end .form-group -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {{--Start company--}}
                                <div class="row" id="company_div" style="display: none;padding-top: 10px;">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px; width: 100%;   margin-top: 10px;" class="form-control" id="client_company" name="client_company_name">
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" for="client_company">Company Name*</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px; width: 100%;   margin-top: 10px;" class="form-control" id="client_company_reg" name="client_company_reg">
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" for="client_company_reg">Registration Number*</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {{--End Company--}}

                                {{--Start individual--}}
                                <div class="row" id="individual_div" style="display: none;padding-top: 10px;">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <select style="margin-top: 25px;" id="identification_document" class="form-control " name="identification_document">
                                                <option value=""> NRIC</option>
                                                <option value=""> FIN</option>
                                                <option value=""> Passport</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" for="identification_document">Identification Document*</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px; width: 100%;   margin-top: 10px;" class="form-control" id="identification_num" name="identification_number">
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" for="identification_number">Identification Number*</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" id="individual_annual_div"  style="display: none;padding-top: 5px;">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <select style="margin-top: 25px;" id="annual_income" class="form-control " name="annual_income">
                                                <option value=""> <10,000 SGD</option>
                                                <option value=""> 10,000 - 30,000 SGD</option>
                                                <option value=""> >30,000 SGD</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" for="annual_income">Annual income</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {{--End individual--}}
                                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="email" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px; width: 100%;   margin-top: 10px;" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" for="email">Email*</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px; width: 100%;   margin-top: 10px;" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" for="Password">Password*</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px; width: 100%;   margin-top: 10px;" class="form-control" id="cnf_password" name="cnf_password">
                                            <label style="font-size: 15px;" for="cnf_password">Confirm Password*</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row" style="padding-left: 18px">
                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-styled tile-text">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="client_terms_checkbox">
                                            <span> I agree with Quesmi’s <u><a href="termsofuse">Terms of Use</a></u> and <u><a href="privacypolicy">Privacy Policy</a></u>.</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%;margin-top: 20px;border-color: #FF0000;background-color: #FF0000;" id="sign_up">Sign Up </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!--end .card-body -->
                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you add HTML form too ?

Comment: yes it is added now.